# how to convert image type to varchar sybase

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase, sap-ase

after some time i landed in sybase (ASE 15.. to be specific) world and i am bit terrified over time 
missing functions and functionality i know from sql server makes me feel like i am in early 90'

to the point
i have to prepare single shot report
an have some text stored as image column (dont know why someone did that)
so what i did was

```
select CAST(CAST(REQUEST AS VARBINARY(16384)) AS VARCHAR(16384))  as RequestBody
from table
```

the problem emarges becouse some requests are longer than 16384 
and have no idea how to get the data

and what is even worse i dont know where to look for information as sybase documentation is in best case scarse, and in comparison with MS world its non existant

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1550/html/blocks/blocks98.htm) you need to use CONVERT function like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(2048), raw_data) as raw_data_str FROM table;
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using varbinary(16384) and varchar(16384), try using varbinary(max) and varchar(max). In that case, the maximum datalength will be 2 GB.

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx

What is the length of the REQUEST column in the table?

Comment: there is no such thing like varbinary(max) in sybase ase, even in your link there is varbinary(n) where 1<n<pageSize where pageMax is 16K (16384), if it only were that simple as using max : )

Comment: My bad! Can you cast the image column to a unitext datatype? Just asking.